# code works in office 2010 and 2016 but doesnt work in office 2007

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please help, as the following code to save file both in excel and pdf format works in office 2016 but does not work on office 2007. can someone please modify the following code for me so that it can also work in office 2007.

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear

Path = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\rohailnisar\"

filename = Range("A1")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled


Dim strFilename     As String
Dim rngRange        As Range

'Considering Sheet1 to be where you need to pick file name
Set rngRange = Worksheets("MIRCALCULATION").Range("A1")

Worksheets("MIRCALCULATION").PageSetup.PrintArea = "c1:u45"
Worksheets("LOAD").PageSetup.PrintArea = "c1:u45"
Worksheets("DR").PageSetup.PrintArea = "c1:J45"
Worksheets("MINUS").PageSetup.PrintArea = "B1:I25"


Sheets(Array("MIRCALCULATION", "DR", "MINUS", "LOAD")).Select
Sheets("MIRCALCULATION").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, filename:=Path & filename




Err_Clear:
 If Err <> 0 Then
 MkDir CreateObject("wscript.shell").specialfolders("desktop") & "\rohailnisar"

 Path = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\rohailnisar\"
 filename = Range("A1")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled


'Considering Sheet1 to be where you need to pick file name
Set rngRange = Worksheets("MIRCALCULATION").Range("A1")

Worksheets("MIRCALCULATION").PageSetup.PrintArea = "c1:u45"
 Worksheets("LOAD").PageSetup.PrintArea = "c1:u45"
Worksheets("DR").PageSetup.PrintArea = "c1:J45"
Worksheets("MINUS").PageSetup.PrintArea = "B1:I25"

Sheets(Array("MIRCALCULATION", "DR", "MINUS", "LOAD")).Select
Sheets("MIRCALCULATION").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=Path & filename

End If





Sheets("MIRCALCULATION").Select

End Sub
```

i can run above code in office 365, but when i try to run the same code it gives me path error on office 2007. most people who will be using this code are on office 2007. so i really need this code to work in office 2007. this basically converts excel sheets into pdf and saves it along with excel file.

Comment: step through the code (using F8) to identify the exact line the error is occurring.

Comment: trying f8 it gives me error on this line Path = Environ("USERPROFILE

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the last escape character...

Path = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\rohailnisar

Comment: It could also have created a new variable "NewPath"

Path = Environ ("USERPROFILE") & "\ Desktop"
NewPath = Path & "\ rohailnisar \"